# Dask equivalent of numpy (convolve + hstack)?

Tags: dask

I currently have a function that computes a sliding sum across a 1-D numpy array (vector) using [`convolve`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) and [`hstack`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html). I would like to create an equivalent function using dask, but the various ways I've tried so far have not worked out.

What I'm trying to do is to compute a "sliding sum" of n numbers of an array, unless any of the numbers are NaN in which case the sum should also be NaN. The (n - 1) elements of the result should also be NaN, since no wrap around/reach behind is assumed.

For example:

```
input vector: [3, 4, 6, 2, 1, 3, 5, np.NaN, 8, 5, 6] 
n: 3
result: [NaN, NaN, 13, 12, 9, 6, 9, NaN, NaN, NaN, 19]
```

or

```
input vector: [1, 5, 7, 2, 3, 4, 9, 6, 3, 8]
n: 4
result: [NaN, NaN, NaN, 15, 17, 16, 18, 22, 22, 26]
```

The function I currently have for this using numpy functions:

```
def sum_to_scale(values, scale):

    # don't bother if the number of values to sum is 1 (will result in duplicate array)
    if scale == 1:
        return values

    # get the valid sliding summations with 1D convolution
    sliding_sums = np.convolve(values, np.ones(scale), mode="valid")

    # pad the first (n - 1) elements of the array with NaN values
    return np.hstack(([np.NaN] * (scale - 1), sliding_sums))
```

How can I do the above using the dask array API (and/or [dask_image.ndfilters](http://image.dask.org/en/latest/dask_image.ndfilters.html?highlight=convolve)) to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: I don't know if this solves your question directly, but the `xclim` package has their `run_length` function which seems to count the number of consecutive `True` values. I wonder if that will serve as a skeleton to sum consecutive values? https://github.com/Ouranosinc/xclim/blob/fdb5bdcbdffb011aa394de794fec987e9422855a/xclim/run_length.py#L12